# Is there a way to pass a given property identifier into a Sub as a parameter in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a generic BubbleSort subroutine to be used throughout my program. As such, I would like to be able to Sort a List by any given Property (e.g. Index, Health, Name etc.) . My issue is that I don't seem to be able to pass a property identifier into the sub. How do I go about implementing this?

I tried to pass the Property in as an object to no avail.

My attempt to call the sub:

```
    AscendingBubbleSort(Party, Character.Health)
```

The Sub itself:

```
Sub AscendingBubbleSort(ByRef List As List(Of Object), ByRef ListProperty As Object)

    Dim Swap As Boolean = False
    Dim Temp As New Object

    Do

        Swap = False

        For i = 0 To ((List).Count - 2)

            If List(i).ListProperty < List(i + 1).ListProperty Then

                Temp = List(i)

                List(i) = List(i + 1)
                List(i + 1) = Temp

                Swap = True

            End If

        Next

    Loop Until Swap = False

End Sub
```

I expected the "Party" List to be sorted by Ascending Health, but my program wouldn't compile, citing the following build error:

reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

with "Character.Health" highlighted as the offending code.

Comment: use a lambda. thats how linq works.

Comment: @DanielA.White - I only know how to do basic LINQ queries and don't really know what a Lambda means in this context. A quick google search of the term hasn't helped much. Care to elaborate on the basics of what it is and how it's used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types) and a [Lamba](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions).

Note that you need to change your comparison from `<` to `>` if you want an **ascending** sort as indicated in the title of your subroutine!

Also note the use of `ByVal` instead of `ByRef` in the parameters.  ByRef is only necessary when you want to point the variable passed in to a completely new instance that is created within the subroutine.

With this setup, you can specify what to sort on like this:

```
AscendingBubbleSort(objects, Function(x) x.SomeProperty)
' < or > 
AscendingBubbleSort(objects, Function(x) x.SomeOtherProperty)
```

The code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim objects As New List(Of SomeClass)
        objects.Add(New SomeClass() With {.SomeProperty = 5, .SomeOtherProperty = "Bob"})
        objects.Add(New SomeClass() With {.SomeProperty = 1, .SomeOtherProperty = "Jane"})
        objects.Add(New SomeClass() With {.SomeProperty = 7, .SomeOtherProperty = "Cathy"})

        AscendingBubbleSort(objects, Function(x) x.SomeOtherProperty)
        For Each sc As SomeClass In objects
            Debug.Print(sc.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub AscendingBubbleSort(Of T)(ByVal List As List(Of T), ByVal ListPropery As Func(Of T, Object))
        Dim Swap As Boolean = False
        Dim Temp As New Object

        Do
            Swap = False
            For i = 0 To ((List).Count - 2)
                If ListPropery(List(i)) > ListPropery(List(i + 1)) Then
                    Temp = List(i)

                    List(i) = List(i + 1)
                    List(i + 1) = Temp

                    Swap = True
                End If
            Next
        Loop Until Swap = False
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class SomeClass

    Public Property SomeProperty As Integer
    Public Property SomeOtherProperty As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return SomeProperty & ": " & SomeOtherProperty
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: In AscendingBubbleSort method, would it be better to declare Temp as T?

Comment: @ajakblackgoat That would make sense.  Good spot!